# Creating Azure Elastic job agent throwing "DatabaseDoesNotExist" Error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am creating Azure Elastic jobs agent and I am attaching a newly created, fresh Azure SQL Database with it, but when I execute the process it gives me this error

```
"error": {
        "code": "DatabaseDoesNotExist",
        "message": "Database 'mydatabase' does not exist."
    }
```

Previously we were created it successfully

[image]

Update:

Actually, the issue was we were selecting the wrong database (hyperscale) type. When select the following tier it worked perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the same resource and it deployed successfully for me. Please find the screenshot for the same below. **I just simply created the SQL server on Azure, then create a Database inside it and used the same database in Elastic Job.**

[image]

As per the official document [Troubleshoot common Azure deployment errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/common-deployment-errors), the **Conflict** error occurs when:

> You're requesting an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's
> current state. For example, disk resizing is allowed only when
> creating a VM or when the VM is deallocated.

[image]

You can check if your database has been deployed successfully without any error. And once it is deployed, you create the elastic job agent using that database. **Make sure your database configuration match the elastic job requirement and you have appropriate permissions.**